# jQuery how to append "

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

I am trying to make a text editor using the `<textarea>` in html. I would like to use jQuery to insert another `"` after I type `"` to make things easier for the user. I have got this to work with brackets however there is an issue with quotation marks as they end the string. I have tried to escape them as below:

`$('#input').append("\"");`

However this just does not append anything.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val()` to set the value of an input, not `.append()`.

```
$("#input").val($("#input").val() + '"');
```

And you can use single quotes around a string that contains double quotes so you don't need to escape them.

Comment: I need to place the quotation marks in front of the cursor which is what the append function does

Comment: No, that's not what the append function does. It's for appending new elements to a container element in the DOM. E.g. `$("#somediv").append("<span>foo</span>")`

Comment: Oh ok, so in that case how could I place a character in front of the cursor?